# Firebase search with param?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

so i just started with Firebase and AngularFire.
I've got this data structure:

```
friends
 -JzKr-mrv-O7rlxrMi3_
     creator: "111181498675628551375"
     description: "dsa"
     name: "das"
 --JzKrahnTf47MXp8nAZx
     creator: "111181498675628551320"
     description: "ddasdassa"
     name: "dasdadsadas"
```

Now i want to query with param creator = "111181498675628551320".
How can i do this ? I've tried this way:

```
 .service('Friends', function ($firebase, store, $state) {
    var friendsRef = new Firebase("url/friends");
    friendsRef.authWithCustomToken(store.get('firebaseToken'), function (error, auth) {
        if (error) {
            // There was an error logging in, redirect the user to login page
            $state.go('login');
        }
    });
    var friendsSync = $firebase(friendsRef);
    var friends = friendsSync.$asArray();
    this.all = function () {
        return friends;
    };
    this.getCreator = function(creator){
        return friends.$getRecord(creator);
    };
});
```

Anyone got maybe some dev reference how i should work with it?
 Maybe i should make other call then url/friends?

Comment: You're using an old version of AngularFire. Please upgrade your code: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/. I'm writing up an answer below, which will use constructs from the 1.x release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularFire is a wrapper around the Firebase JavaScript SDK, which simplifies binding Firebase data to AngularJS views. When something is not obvious from the AngularFire documentation, refer to the [Firebase JavaScript documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/).

You can read all about [Firebase queries in the documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries). In that case what you'll need to do, is build the necessary query using Firebase's regular JavaScript SDK:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/friends');
var query = ref.orderByChild('creator').equalTo('111181498675628551320');
```

Then you can bind the resulting items to your view by using an AngularFire `$firebaseArray()`:

```
$scope.friends = $firebaseArray(query);
```